# Outcome of a MailSendException thrown by Spring JavaMailSender send method (multi-message argument)

Tags: spring, smtp, jakarta-mail

My question relates to Spring `JavaMailSender`. Especially about the send method that takes an array of `MimeMessages`.

[See javadocs for JavaMailSender' send method.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSender.html#send-javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage...-)

I am wondering what happens when within an array of say 5 messages, the 3rd message cannot be sent and results in a `MailSendException`.

Are the first 2 messages actually delivered or none of the 5 messages delivered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the javadocs, it looks like it sends everything it can and collects all the failures in a Map that you can access using the getFailedMessages method.